# ¿Como imprimir el resultado al accionar un boton en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

hola soy bastante nuevo en esto de la programacion y el profesor nos encargo crear un programa que nos de el precio de un mensaje analizando letra por letra si es un digito carater o caracter especial dandonos un precio dependiendo que que contenia el mensaje simulando una especie de" telegrafo"
el problema resulta que cuando intento pasar el codigo a interfaz grafica tkinter deja de funcionar ya que en donde se supone que se imprimira el resultado no muestra nada y no se que estoy haciendo mal

```
import tkinter as tk


dinero = 0
digitos = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
carateres = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x","y", "z")
caracteresespeciales = ("ñ", "ü", "é", "á", "í", "ó", "ú")


def calculaprecio():
    mensaje = str(entrada1.get())  # escribimos el mensajeo
    len(mensaje)  # nos calcula la longitud del mensaje
    longitudmensaje = len(mensaje)  # una variavle toma el valor de la longitud del mensaje
    indice = 0
    global dinero

    while indice < longitudmensaje:  # siempre y cuando el indice no tome un valor mas alto que la pcicion del ultimo caracter el ciclo continua
        letra = mensaje[indice]  # la letra sera equivalente al el caracter cuya pocicion sera determinada por el indice
        if letra in carateres:
            dinero = dinero + 10  # si la letra analizada es un caracter se suma 10 pesos al dinero
        if letra in digitos:
            dinero = dinero + 20  # si la letra analizada es un digito se suman 20 pesos al dinero
        if letra in caracteresespeciales:
            dinero = dinero + 30  # si la letra analizada es un caracter especial se suman 30 pesos al dinero
        indice += 1  # se suma uno al indice para camiar la pocicion actual
        return var.set(dinero)


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("telegrafo") # titulo de la ventana
ventana.geometry('380x300')# dimenciones de la ventana
ventana.resizable(False,False)# esta parte sirve para que el usuario no pueda modificar el tamaño de la ventana
ventana.configure(background='dark blue')# esta parte corresponde al color de fondo de la ventana

var=tk.StringVar()# en esta parte se va a guardar el resultado que retornen las funicones 

# esta parte corresponde a un cuadro de texto que indica ingresar el primer dato, bg es el color del cuadro y fg el de la fuente de escritura
ventana1=tk.Label(ventana,text="ingresa tu mensaje ",bg="black",fg="white")
# esta parte corresponde a la dimencion del cuadro del texto
ventana1.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
# en esta parte se encuentra un cuadro vacio donde se pueden ingresar los datos
entrada1 = tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

botonprecio=tk.Button(ventana,text="enviar mensaje",fg="blue",command=calculaprecio()).place(x=160,y=80)

#esta parte se encarga de mostrar un mensaje
precio=tk.Label(ventana,text="costo de su mensaje ",bg="black",fg="white").place(x=150,y=190)

# en esta parte se imprime el resultado de cualquiera de las funciones seleccionadas anteriormente
res=tk.Label(ventana,bg="plum",textvariable=var,padx=5,pady=5,width=50).place(x=8,y=220)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

acá hay un error:

```
botonprecio=tk.Button(ventana,text="enviar mensaje",fg="blue",command=calculaprecio()).place(x=160,y=80)
```

cuando haces un call a las funciones se usa el nombre y el (), pero al llamar a funciones con command en tk no funciona así, o sea lo correcto en este caso sería solo el nombre de la función:

```
botonprecio=tk.Button(ventana,text="enviar mensaje",fg="blue",command=calculaprecio).place(x=160,y=80)
```

como comentario:
hay formas con menos código de comprobar:

```
import string
#biblioteca necesaria
mensaje = "verano2020"
for letra in mensaje:  #recorremos la cadena 
    if letra in string.ascii_lowercase: # genera la cadena con minúsculas
                                        # reemplaza a la tupla caracteres
        print("10")
    elif letra in string.digits: # reemplaza a tu tupla dígitos
        print("20")
```

por supuesto que esto es demostrativo, no obligatorio